# Relative extension groups

Tags: ring-theory, representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring and $S$ a subring of $R$, both unital with the same 1.  Then for $R$-modules $M,N$, Hochschild defined the relative extension groups $\operatorname{Ext}^i_{(R,S)}(M,N)$ which can be defined by taking an $S$-split injective resolution of $N$ and an $S$ split projective resolution of $M$, applying $\operatorname{Hom}_{R}(-,-)$ to obtain a complex and taking cohomology (for the details see Hochschild's paper, 'Relative Homological Algebra'.)

In the paper, he states that $\operatorname{Ext}^1_{(R,S)}(M,N)$ is 'isomorphic to the group of equivalence classes of $S$-trivial extensions of $N$ by $M$'.

My question is what precisely this group is---I'm concerned I am missing a subtlety.  In particular is the $S$-splitting of an exact sequence $0\to N\to V\to M\to 0$ a part of the data of an element in this extension group?

**The statement** I truly need to verify is the following: suppose that $0\to N\to V\to M\to 0$ is an $S$-split sequence which is *also* split over $R$. Then does it always define the trivial element of $\operatorname{Ext}^1_{(R,S)}(M,N)$?  Or is the $S$-splitting a non-trivial piece of data?